# CLion: mingw not found reported by cmake

Tags: mingw, clion, mingw-w64

[cmake window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUI8W.png)

[toolchain config window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l84fh.png)

I could not make CLion's cmake running because it says "mingw not found". How can I deal with it?

Comment: This is happening because the `Make` path is not correct. You should re-check it. Also, you should check if the correct MinGW path is actually the path you entered in `Environment`.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem seems not to be this case. I have asked this at intellj support website. see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4614942885394-Msys2-Mingw-environment-is-not-detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions can be found: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4614942885394-Msys2-Mingw-environment-is-not-detected, the cause of this might be a new commit to MINGW making CLion unable to detect Toolchain even you specify. so to solve this, just download CLion 2022 EAP and import settings from the old version.

But before trying this approach, check if your config about Toolchain is correct

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).